# How to Install pyhdf library on python 3?

Tags: python, python3, libraries

I  have both python version 2.7 and 3.5.3 but I need to install pyhdf library on python version 3.5.3. How can I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install it later.I took some help from here https://gist.github.com/eightysteele/1408088. I used the following code

```
cd pyhdf-0.9.0
export INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/hdf
export LIBRARY_DIRS=/usr/lib
export NOSZIP=1
python3 setup.py install
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

only thing we need to do for installing it in python3 is write python3 instead of python

Answer (score 0):

I got answer yesterday after asking this in the github issue.

use conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python=3.7 pyhdf
```